# Why JSONObject converts stringified array to JSONArray on put operation? How to stop this?

Tags: java, json

- When I tried to put stringified array in JSONObject, it became a JSONArray. But I want to keep the stringified array. Any help will be appreciated.

eg:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONOject();

jsonObj.put("stringified_array", "[1,2]");
```

So, when I debugged it, the jsonObj properties were

```
key : "stringified_array", value : [1,2] (JSONArray)
```

**Edit:**
Here is the link for sample code: https://onlinegdb.com/UbV6VXvpJ.
Code won't compile due to missing packages in online ide, just for better understanding of scenario I have added the link.

Comment: JSONObject is A modifiable set of name/value mappings. Names are unique, non-null strings. So it is working as expected. What you are trying to achieve? I think you need JSONArray.

Comment: Please look at the above example. If I put a stringified array in JSONObject, I want it to be in the same format(string). But it changes to JSONArray.

Comment: Hello @Sivaraman, you're not right, because its a key/value Map or HashMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is why, if you look at the declaraction of constructor of **JSONObject**, you will find what you are looking for. One of the constructor of **JSONObject** class looks like following:

```
public org.json.JSONObject put(java.lang.String key, java.util.Map<?,?> value) throws org.json.JSONException { /* compiled code */ }
```

If you know **how to do reverse engineering**, you should be able to find more about the actual implementation :)!

Hopefully, this will help you out!

Comment: I checked the same using HashMap, got the same output. Thanks, your answer helped.